# How to break a while loop upon an empty input python?

Tags: python, while-loop, break, valueerror

I have a code where the user is asked to input two integers, separated by a " ". This should continue as long as the user does not input anything, causing a ValueError, and breaking the While loop. However, I can't figure out what am I doing wrong:

```
def syote():
 koepisteet_all = []
 harjoitukset_all = []
 while True:
    koepisteet, harjoitukset = input('Koepisteet ja harjoitusten määrä: ').split()
    if ValueError:
        break
    else:
        koepisteet_all.append(koepisteet)
        harjoitukset_all.append(harjoitukset)


print(koepisteet_all)
print(harjoitukset_all) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
     
syote()
```

As wished, I do get a ValueError "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)", but the code stops running.

Comment: Use `try/except` to catch errors, not `if`.

Comment: I don't get it : you say "should continue" and "break the loop" at the same time, should it ask again or stop ?

Comment: With the current indentation, thet function `syote()` ends after the while loop. Did you want the two print statements to be executed after the loop? Then you have to indent them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `try/except` structure :

- if a `ValueError` is raises (because of wrong input), then stop with `break`
- if 2 values are given, save them

```py
def syote():
    koepisteet_all, harjoitukset_all = [], []
    while True:
        try:
            koepisteet, harjoitukset = input('Koepisteet ja harjoitusten määrä: ').split()
            koepisteet_all.append(koepisteet)
            harjoitukset_all.append(harjoitukset)
        except ValueError:
            break

    print(koepisteet_all)
    print(harjoitukset_all)
```

Comment: `break` should be in the `except`

Comment: Appending to the lists should be inside the `while`

Comment: @Barmar owww I understood the quesiton the opposite : give one good value and stop, thanks :D

Comment: He said it poorly.

Comment: I think he meant "until", not "as long as"